# Uniform continuity of $f(x)=x+\frac{\sin x}{x}$ in $(0,\infty)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, uniform-continuity

> Prove the following function is uniformly continuous: $f(x)=x+\frac{\sin x}{x}$ in $(0,\infty)$.

I thought of trying to show that the derivative is bounded thus the function is lipschitz and we're done but the derivative isn't bounded.

Second try: I know that if $f,g$ are continuous then $f+g$ is continuous as well. $x$ is known to be uniformly continuous, so we're left with showing that $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is lipschitz  <strike>which is easy and we're done.</strike>

Is my approach correct ?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes seems fine to me..your second approach

Comment: @Vishesh thanks, there's no need to even show that it's lipschitz, I can just say the it's bounded and show it with limits and that's it.

Comment: If you can show that the derivative of $(\sin x)/x$ is bounded, then the same argument applies to the derivative of $x + (\sin x)/x$.  Why do you say the latter is hard to prove Lipschitz but the former is easy?

Comment: @ErickWong I could be wrong, and apparently I am. The derivative of sinx/x isn't bounded so I'm back to square one.

Comment: @GinKin Can you show that the derivative of $(\sin x)/x$ is bounded if you restrict $x$ a little bit?  (BTW don't worry, the derivative actually **is** bounded everywhere even if it isn't obvious at first.)

Comment: @ErickWong the derivative is : $$\dfrac{\cos\left(x\right)}{x}-\dfrac{\sin\left(x\right)}{{x}^{2}}$$ cosx/x and sinx/x^2 go to infinity as x tend to 0. So it isn't bounded. How is it possible to restrict x in this case ?

Comment: @GinKin, your argument is wrong. You can't calculate a limit of $\infty - \infty$ by simply saying it's $\infty$. It's undefined and you need to use some other way. Taylor series for $\sin(x)$ is $x - x^3 / 6 + \cdots$ so that $\sin(x)/x$ = $1 - x^2 / 6 + \cdots$ has $0$ derivative at $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know $f_1(x) \equiv x$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$.   You need to show $f_2(x) \equiv \sin(x)/x$  is uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$.

All you need to do is show $f_2$ can be extended continuously to $[0,\infty)$ and  show $f_2(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.  It follows easily that $f_2$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$ (use the fact that a continuous function on a compact interval is uniformly continuous on that interval).  In fact, any continuous function $g:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ with a finite limit $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$.

HINT: let $\epsilon > 0$.  Let $a > 0$ be big enough so that for $x_1, x_2 \geq a$, $|f_2(x_1)-f_2(x_2)| < \epsilon/2$.  $f_2$ is uniformly continuous on the compact interval $[0, a+1]$.  Now you have to find $\delta > 0$ so that if $x_1, x_2 \geq 0$ with $|x_1-x_2| < \delta$, then $|f_2(x_1)-f_2(x_2)|<\epsilon$. HINT: if $\delta< 1$, then $x_1$ and $x_2$ are both in $[0,a+1]$ or both in $[a,\infty)$.

So you don't need to find, use, or estimate the derivative of $\sin(x)/x$. That derivative actually is bounded, but you don't need that property (by the way, there are uniformly continuous functions on $[0,\infty)$ with unbounded derivative, such as $\sin(e^x)/(x^2+1)$).

Comment: What do you mean by extending it ?

Comment: @GinKin : Enlarging the domain of the function.  $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin(x)/x = 1$, so define $f(0)$ for your $f$ by $f(0) = 0 + 1 = 1$.  Now $f$ has domain $[0,\infty)$.  This is good because $[0,a]$ is compact for $a>0$, while $(0.a]$ is not.

Comment: Why does infinity can be considered part of a compact interval ? Shouldn't the interval be closed ?

Comment: @GinKin : infinity is not part of a compact interval.  I added some more hints to my answer.