# Prove uniform contininuity (probably by Lipschitz continuity)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, continuity

Prove uniform continuity at $(0,\infty)$ for:
$$f(x) = x + \frac{\sin (x)}{x}$$

Derivative is:
$$f'(x) = \frac{x\cos (x) - \sin (x) + x^2}{x^2}$$

so, taking the limit at $\infty$ I got the value of $1$.
Looking at the graph I see infinite numbers of maximum points converges to $1$ of course.

Wolfram-alpha is telling me there is no global maximum (this is kinda weird, isn't it?).
Anyway, what should I do next? by looking at the graph it is sure can be bounded by a line. I just don't know how to describe it mathematically.

Comment: Hint: $x$ is uniformly continuous, then on $[0,100]$ we have uniform continuity of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$, finally, on $(100, \infty)$ the function has a bounded derivative.

Comment: In MathJax, LaTeX, etc., there's no need to write {{{expression}}} where {expression} will do.  See my edits to the question.

Comment: The derivative is bounded on all its domain.

Comment: I'm using MathType by the way

Comment: @TZakrevskiy, I think I proved before that if $f(x), g(x)$ are uniformly continuous than $f(x) + g(x)$. Anyway, I'm not sure what you did by dividing the domain into two "chunks". Can you explain it better please?

Comment: @GitGud: of course, you're right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uniform continuity of $f(x)=x+\frac{\sin x}{x}$ in $(0,\infty)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/626966/uniform-continuity-of-fx-x-frac-sin-xx-in-0-infty)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TZakrevskiy provided the critical observation in his comment, but I'll try to expand on why it's a natural perspective to take here. Intuitively, your function $f(x)$ is well-behaved near $0$ and near $\infty$ but in different ways. Near the origin, you're essentially looking at the function $\sin x /x$, which you probably are aware can be extended to a continuous function on $[0,\varepsilon]$ for any $\varepsilon$.

At the same time, you've mentioned that $f'(x)$ is bounded as $x \to \infty$ and hence uniformly continuous on $[\varepsilon,\infty)$ for sufficiently large $\varepsilon$ (and in fact for any $\varepsilon > 0$ since $f'$ is continuous$).

Accordingly, a proof of the uniform continuity of $f$ should be broken into two parts, where you establish the uniform continuity of $f$ near $0$ and $\infty$ separately. One way to make this precise is sketched as follows:

- Note $f$ extends to a continuous function $\hat f$ on $[0,\infty)$, which I'll now refer to as $f$ from now on.
- Pick you favorite $\varepsilon \in (0,\infty)$ (any will do). You know without any work that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\varepsilon]$ (why?). (BTW: This is why we extend $f$.)
- Show that $f'$ is bounded on $[\varepsilon,\infty)$, and conclude accordingly that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[\varepsilon,\infty)$. (BTW: If you haven't seen this proof, try to proof bounded derivative $\implies$ u.c. on your own. It's a great exercise!)
- Conclude that $f$ is continuous on $(0,\infty) \subset [0,\varepsilon]\cup[\varepsilon,\infty)$. (If you haven't explicitly thought about why this is, do so now.)

Comment: Wow, Thanks! Can I take for granted the fact $sin(x) \over x$ is continuous?

Comment: Didn't you mean $[0, \epsilon]$ in the second bullet?

Comment: @AndrePoole: If this is for a class, that's between you and the grader! `:)` Seriously though, it's worth stating explicitly that the extension of $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ (which comes down to showing the extension of $\sin x/x$ is continuous), since the rest of the argument depends on this fact. Also, it can be done quickly (if you take the existence of $\lim_{x\to0^+}\sin x/x$ for granted).

Comment: @AndrePoole: I somehow managed to switch from $\varepsilon$s to $a$s halfway through my answer! I'll correct my response. Thanks for catching this!

Answer (score 3):

$f'(x) = \frac{x\cos (x) - \sin (x) + x^2}{x^2}$ can be extended to a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ (check that $\lim _{x \rightarrow 0}f'(x)=1$). Thus it is bounded on the interval $[-1,1]$.

To show that $f'$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$ it remains to show that it is bounded on $[1,\infty]$ and $[-\infty,-1]$.

Let us first consider $[1,\infty]$, for $x\geq1$ we have that

$$\frac{x\cos (x) - \sin (x) + x^2}{x^2}\leq\frac{x^2+x}{x^2}\leq\frac{2x^2}{x^2}=2$$

It is equally easy to see that $f'$ is bounded on $[-\infty,-1]$. I leave this case for you to work out.

Comment: How did you know to choose taking the limit at $0$?